# any cpu implement instruction prefetch both branch of a branch instruction

Tags: caching, cpu

As mainstream cpu use instruction prefetch to enhance their performance,

what I wonder is can any cpu prefetch both branch of an branch-instruction

so that if the predication failure, we can ensure the instruction already in iCache.

as a example:

```
L_main:
  ...
  add 10, %rax
  cmp %rax, %rbx
  je  L10
  add 20, %rbx
  ...
L10:
  add 20, %rcx
  ...
```

instruction-prefetcher can prefetch both instruction at **L10** and after **je L10**.

Answer (score 0):

yes basically it's possible, the Branch Prediction Unit always hold both paths of a branch.

The question however is if they should, pay in mind that too aggressive prefetches has bad effect, since you can slow down real transactions.
Modern CPUs has prediction accurate of 90%-95% and very long pipeline which means that you will have to bring the prefetch long before the actual execution, so you will have more branches on the way from the branch being execute to the branch you need to prefetch and it's exponentially (if you prefetch both paths of each branch).

Maybe it's good to prefetch also the non-predicted path for branches that the BPU doesn't have strong confident in their prediction (you can also add some condition that the bus is not too busy).